# Will this short range AM transmitter constructed using crystal work?

Tags: rf, oscillator, radio

I have designed a circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUIGeH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a few corrections in the circuit. I couldn't do it in the editor because I don't know. The corrections are: 
1. The input is audio input.
2. The capacitor is electrolytic.

Now my question is whether this circuit will be able to generate the carrier frequency to transmit the audio input. If not, then what are all the required additions and corrections?

Also can anyone explain how to design the receiver to receive the signals.

Comment: there is no way this circuit is gonna work. I mean, this only propagates so so sooo less parasitics as carrier frequency. Below -90 dBm. Maybe...

Comment: I know. That is why I asked what should be done to make it a proper transmitter?

Comment: If the intention is to turn on and off the crystal as if it is an oscillator then look up how crystals are used... it is not a case of turning on power..it has to be in a feedback loop to oscillate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is whether this circuit will be able to generate the
>   carrier frequency to transmit the audio input. If not, then what are
>   all the required additions and corrections?

My advice is do some research and forget your circuit. Google is your friend. Type "crystal AM modulator" and look at the images that it finds: -

[image]

Next choose one that appears to give good information about how it works and try it out. Also be very aware of your country's laws on illegal transmitters.

> Also can anyone explain how to design the receiver to receive the
>   signals.

Get your transmitter working on a band that a regular transistor radio works on then think about designing a receiver (much trickier).

Answer (score -3):

This is not much of an answer, but a blind suggestion since I know nothing about transistor parameters and other conditions. First, if you want to modulate the signal you should multiply them instead of summing them. Secondly, there must be an adjusted resistor on the place where the crystal is. Because the crystal does not let dc current to flow so there will be no amplified signal. Third, you should place the antenna on collector output with a coupling capacitor with a large value  say 1.5 uF. Then you should reduce the value of the source resistor. And final, put the crystal to source with proper capacitor values. That means you should also bypass the source resistor.

Comment: if you know absolutely nothing about it, why are you answering it?

Comment: Wow! How many negative votes I get! :) I thought that was an exam question or something. Teachs may ask some stupid questions like this. Also I do not know the transistor but I may re arrange the configuration of the circuit. And I was being polite, I think my answer is right. Anyway, I am sorry if I made a mistake in my respond.